# Cannot access empty string from array of strings in C

Tags: c, gdb

I'm using an array of strings in C to hold arguments given to a custom shell.  I initialize the array of buffers using:

```
char *args[MAX_CHAR];
```

Once I parse the arguments, I send them to the following function to determine the type of IO redirection if there are any (this is just the first of 3 functions to check for redirection and it only checks for STDIN redirection).

```
int parseInputFile(char **args, char *inputFilePath) {
    char *inputSymbol = "<";
    int isFound = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARG; i++) {
        if (strlen(args[i]) == 0) {
            isFound = 0;
            break;
        }
        if ((strcmp(args[i], inputSymbol)) == 0) {
            strcpy(inputFilePath, args[i+1]);
            isFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isFound;
}
```

Once I compile and run the shell, it crashes with a SIGSEGV.  Using GDB I determined that the shell is crashing on the following line:

```
if (strlen(args[i]) == 0) {
```

This is because the address of `arg[i]` (the first empty string after the parsed commands) is inaccessible.  Here is the error from GDB and all relevant variables:

```
(gdb) next
359         if (strlen(args[i]) == 0) {
(gdb) p args[0]
$1 = 0x7fffffffe570 "echo"
(gdb) p args[1]
$2 = 0x7fffffffe575 "test"
(gdb) p args[2]
$3 = 0x0
(gdb) p i
$4 = 2
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
parseInputFile (args=0x7fffffffd570, inputFilePath=0x7fffffffd240 "") at shell.c:359
359         if (strlen(args[i]) == 0) {
```

I believe that the `p args[2]` returning `$3 = 0x0` means that because the index has yet to be written to, it is mapped to address `0x0` which is out of the bounds of execution.  Although I can't figure out why this is because it was declared as a buffer.  Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

EDIT: Per Kaylum's comment, here is a minimal reproducible example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<readline/readline.h>
#include<readline/history.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// Defined values
#define MAX_CHAR 256
#define MAX_ARG 64
#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J")  // Clear window
#define DEFAULT_PROMPT_SUFFIX "> "

char PROMPT[MAX_CHAR], SPATH[1024];


int parseInputFile(char **args, char *inputFilePath) {
    char *inputSymbol = "<";
    int isFound = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARG; i++) {
        if (strlen(args[i]) == 0) {
            isFound = 0;
            break;
        }
        if ((strcmp(args[i], inputSymbol)) == 0) {
            strcpy(inputFilePath, args[i+1]);
            isFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isFound;
}

int ioRedirectHandler(char **args) {
    char inputFilePath[MAX_CHAR] = "";

    // Check if any redirects exist
    if (parseInputFile(args, inputFilePath)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void parseArgs(char *cmd, char **cmdArgs) {
    int na;
    // Separate each argument of a command to a separate string
    for (na = 0; na < MAX_ARG; na++) {
        cmdArgs[na] = strsep(&cmd, " ");
        if (cmdArgs[na] == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        if (strlen(cmdArgs[na]) == 0) {
            na--;
        }
    }
}

int processInput(char* input, char **args, char **pipedArgs) {
    // Parse the single command and args
    parseArgs(input, args);
    return 0;
}

int getInput(char *input) {
    char *buf, loc_prompt[MAX_CHAR] = "\n";

    strcat(loc_prompt, PROMPT);
    buf = readline(loc_prompt);
    if (strlen(buf) != 0) {
        add_history(buf);
        strcpy(input, buf);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void init() {
    char *uname;
    clear();
    uname = getenv("USER");
    printf("\n\n \t\tWelcome to Student Shell, %s! \n\n", uname);
    
    // Initialize the prompt
    snprintf(PROMPT, MAX_CHAR, "%s%s", uname, DEFAULT_PROMPT_SUFFIX);
}

int main() {
    char input[MAX_CHAR];
    char *args[MAX_CHAR], *pipedArgs[MAX_CHAR];
    int isPiped = 0, isIORedir = 0;
    init();

    while(1) {
        // Get the user input
        if (getInput(input)) {
            continue;
        }
        isPiped = processInput(input, args, pipedArgs);

        isIORedir = ioRedirectHandler(args);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: If I forgot to include any important information, please let me know and I can get it updated.

Comment: We cannot help with incomplete code. Please provide complete code as a [mre]. That is, the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kaylum I have updated the question to contain a minimal reproducible example and verified that the error is the same using GDB.

Comment: "*I initialize the array of buffers using*". No, that is not initialisation. Variables declared on the stack are not initialised and contains indetermnate values. Init like this: `char *args[MAX_CHAR] = { 0 };`

Comment: Then you need to change `if (strlen(args[i]) == 0)` to be `if (args[i] == NULL)`. That is, you need to check the pointer value and not try to access it with `strlen` before you have verified it is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```c
char *args[MAX_CHAR];
```

you allocate room for `MAX_CHAR` pointers to `char`. You do not initialise the array. If it is a global variable, you will have initialised all the pointers to `NULL`, but you do it in a function, so the elements in the array can point anywhere. You should not dereference them before you have set the pointers to point at something you are allowed to access.

You also do this, though, in `parseArgs()`, where you do this:

```c
    cmdArgs[na] = strsep(&cmd, " ");
```

There are two potential issues here, but let's deal with the one you hit first. When `strsep()` is through the tokens you are splitting, it returns `NULL`. You test for that to get out of `parseArgs()` so you already know this. However, where your program crashes you seem to have forgotten this again. You call `strlen()` on a `NULL` pointer, and that is a no-no.

There is a difference between `NULL` and the empty string. An empty string is a pointer to a buffer that has the zero char first; the string "" is a pointer to a location that holds the character '\0'. The `NULL` pointer is a special value for pointers, often address zero, that means that the pointer doesn't point anywhere. Obviously, the `NULL` pointer cannot point to an empty string. You need to check if an argument is `NULL`, not if it is the empty string.

If you want to check both for `NULL` and the empty string, you could do something like

```c
if (!args[i] || strlen(args[i]) == 0) {
```

If `args[i]` is `NULL` then `!args[i]` is true, so you will enter the `if` body if you have `NULL` or if you have a pointer to an empty string.

(You could also check the empty string with `!(*args[i])`; `*args[i]` is the first character that `args[i]` points at. So `*args[i]` is zero if you have the empty string; zero is interpreted as false, so `!(*args[i])` is true if and only if `args[i]` is the empty string. Not that this is more readable, but it shows again the difference between empty strings and `NULL`).

I mentioned another issue with the parsed arguments. Whether it is a problem or not depends on the application. But when you parse a string with `strsep()`, you get pointers into the parsed string. You have to be careful not to free that string (it is `input` in your `main()` function) or to modify it after you have parsed the string. If you change the string, you have changed what all the parsed strings look at. You do not do this in your program, so it isn't a problem here, but it is worth keeping in mind. If you want your parsed arguments to survive longer than they do now, after the next command is passed, you need to copy them. The next command that is passed will change them as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`

```
char input[MAX_CHAR];
char *args[MAX_CHAR], *pipedArgs[MAX_CHAR];
```

are all uninitialized. They contain indeterminate values. This could be a potential source of bugs, but is not the reason here, as

- `getInput` modifies the contents of `input` to be a valid string before any reads occur.
- `pipedArgs` is unused, so raises no issues (yet).
- `args` is modified by `parseArgs` to (possibly!) contain a NULL sentinel value, without any indeterminate pointers being read first.

---

Firstly, in `parseArgs` it is possible to completely fill `args` without setting the NULL sentinel value that other parts of the program should rely on.

Looking deeper, in `parseInputFile` the following

```
if (strlen(args[i]) == 0)
```

contradicts the limits imposed by `parseArgs` that disallows empty strings in the array. More importantly, `args[i]` may be the sentinel NULL value, and `strlen` expects a non-NULL pointer to a valid string.

This termination condition should simply check if `args[i]` is NULL.

With

```
strcpy(inputFilePath, args[i+1]);
```

`args[i+1]` might also be the NULL sentinel value, and `strcpy` also expects non-NULL pointers to valid strings. You can see this in action when `inputSymbol` is a match for the final token in the array.

`args[i+1]` may also evaluate as `args[MAX_ARGS]`, which would be out of bounds.

Additionally, `inputFilePath` has a string *length* limit of `MAX_CHAR - 1`, and `args[i+1]` is (possibly!) a dynamically allocated string whose length might exceed this.

---

Some edge cases found in `getInput`:

Both arguments to

```
strcat(loc_prompt, PROMPT);
```

are of the size `MAX_CHAR`. Since `loc_prompt` has a *length* of `1`. If `PROMPT` has the length `MAX_CHAR - 1`, the resulting string will have the length `MAX_CHAR`. This would leave no room for the NUL terminating byte.

[`readline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) can return NULL in some situations, so

```
buf = readline(loc_prompt);
if (strlen(buf) != 0) {
```

can again pass the NULL pointer to `strlen`.

A similar issue as before, on success `readline` returns a string of dynamic length, and

```
strcpy(input, buf);
```

can cause a buffer overflow by attempting to copy a string greater in length than `MAX_CHAR - 1`.

`buf` is a pointer to data allocated by `malloc`. It's unclear what `add_history` does, but this pointer must eventually be passed to `free`.

---

Some considerations.

Firstly, it is a good habit to initialize your data, even if it might not matter.

Secondly, using constants (`#define MAX_CHAR 256`) might help to reduce *magic numbers*, but they can lead you to design your program too rigidly if used in the same way.

Consider building your functions to accept a *limit* as an argument, and return a *length*. This allows you to more strictly track the sizes of your data, and prevents you from always designing around the maximum potential case.

A slightly contrived example of designing like this. We can see that `find` does not have to concern itself with possibly checking `MAX_ARGS` elements, as it is told precisely how long the list of valid elements is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ARGS 100

char *get_input(char *dest, size_t sz, const char *display) {
    char *res;

    if (display)
        printf("%s", display);

    if ((res = fgets(dest, sz, stdin)))
        dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0';

    return res;
}

size_t find(char **list, size_t length, const char *str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (strcmp(list[i], str) == 0)
            return i;

    return length;
}

size_t split(char **list, size_t limit, char *source, const char *delim) {
    size_t length = 0;
    char *token;

    while (length < limit && (token = strsep(&source, delim)))
        if (*token)
            list[length++] = token;

    return length;
}

int main(void) {
    char input[512] = { 0 };
    char *args[MAX_ARGS] = { 0 };

    puts("Welcome to the shell.");

    while (1) {
        if (get_input(input, sizeof input, "$ ")) {
            size_t argl = split(args, MAX_ARGS, input, " ");
            size_t redirection = find(args, argl, "<");

            puts("Command parts:");

            for (size_t i = 0; i < redirection; i++)
                printf("%zu: %s\n", i, args[i]);

            puts("Input files:");

            if (redirection == argl)
                puts("[[NONE]]");
            else for (size_t i = redirection + 1; i < argl; i++)
                printf("%zu: %s\n", i, args[i]);

        }
    }
}
```